# Entity Framework - Why Does This Work?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, entity-framework

I'm sure most people ask why things don't work. I am goIng to mix it up by asking why this does work.

```
private SmokeFireDBEntities dbContext = null; 
private IList<MemberResponse> gridData = new List<MemberResponse>();

private void UserControl_Initialized(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.dbContext = new SmokeFireDBEntities(); 
    var members = from m in dbContext.Members
                 where new[] { "A", "P", "S", "J" }.Contains(m.Class.ShortName)
                 orderby m.Line
                 select m;

    foreach (Member m in members)
    {
        MemberResponse mr = new MemberResponse();
        mr.MemberID = m.ID;
        mr.Member = m;
        this.gridData.Add(mr);
    }
    PercentageGrid.ItemsSource = this.gridData;
}

private void SaveButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    AlarmTotal at = new AlarmTotal();

    at.Month = Convert.ToByte(this.MonthField.Text);
    at.Year = Convert.ToInt16(this.YearField.Text);
    at.NumAlarms = Convert.ToInt16(this.TotalAlarmsField.Text);

    this.dbContext.AlarmTotals.AddObject(at);
    this.dbContext.SaveChanges();

    // WHY IS THE FOLLOWING CODE NOT NECESSARY???
    //foreach (MemberResponse mr in this.PercentageGrid.Items)
    //{
    //    mr.AlarmTotalID = at.ID;
    //    this.dbContext.MemberResponses.AddObject(mr);
    //}

    //this.dbContext.SaveChanges();  
}

<UserControl.Resources>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="NameColumnTemplate">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Member.LastName}" />
                <TextBlock Text=", " />
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Member.FirstName}" />
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="InputColumnTemplate">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=NumAttended}" Name="MonthResponse" Width="60" />
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </UserControl.Resources>

    <Grid Background="WhiteSmoke" Height="353" Width="509">
        <TextBox Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="12,33,0,0" Name="MonthField" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" />
        <TextBox Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="93,33,0,0" Name="YearField" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="59" />
        <TextBox Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="158,33,0,0" Name="TotalAlarmsField" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="115" />

        <ListView Margin="1,67,0,0" Name="PercentageGrid" ItemsSource="Binding" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Width="507" Height="286" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
            <ListView.View>
                <GridView>
                    <GridView.Columns>
                        <GridViewColumn Header="Name" CellTemplate="{StaticResource NameColumnTemplate}" />
                        <GridViewColumn Header="Line#" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Member.Line}" />
                        <GridViewColumn Header="Class" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Member.Class.ShortName}" />
                        <GridViewColumn Header="Response" CellTemplate="{StaticResource InputColumnTemplate}" />
                    </GridView.Columns>
                </GridView>
            </ListView.View>
        </ListView>
```

I have removed unnecessary code to shorten this a bit. I am completely new to C#, .NET and everything that goes with it. I am completely stumped as to why this works at all. When I call the first dbContext.SaveChanges() to save the record to "AlarmTotals" it also saves all the "MemberResponse" records at the same time, and even more amazingly has the correct AlarmTotals.ID field populated. This one is really throwing me off, I just can't understand how this works seemingly by magic.

Any insight and explaination would be greatly appreciated. I really want to understand what is going on here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To add to what others said, I guess that the "magic" happens in the line 5:

```
1 foreach (Member m in members)
2 {
3     MemberResponse mr = new MemberResponse();
4     mr.MemberID = m.ID;
5     mr.Member = m;
6     this.gridData.Add(mr);
7 }
```

This is the line that causes your new MemberResponse to attach to current EF ObjectContext (and subsequently, causes them to save on SaveChanges()). MemberResponse.Member is a EF navigation property.

But are you sure that saved MemberResponses have MemberResponse.AlarmTotalID  set correctly? The code doesn't look like it is. The best way to understand what really happened is to **put a breakpoint in the setter of AlarmTotalID property**.

Comment: Yes, I am sure that the correct AlarmTotalID was added to the MemberResponse records. Thats what amazes me even more than the records being added, since I see no way for it to get the correct context for this. Maybe it is just using the last record added? I am going to follow up on your suggestion about the breakpoint and see if I can get a better understanding of whats going on. Thanks

Comment: Maybe there is a default or a trigger in the database that applies these changes?

Comment: @NickSperling ands surfen: I agree with this answer. It is imho impossible that `mr.AlarmTotalID` will be set with the newly created ID in the code you are showing. You just create a new `AlarmTotal`, you set three scalar properties (I guess these are not FK properties) and no navigation property to another entity. And no other entity refers to that new `at`. Setting the `AlarmTotalID` must happen somwhere else. Maybe the breakpoint test will show.

Comment: I swear it was working correctly. However, I reworked the code to have an AlarmTotal object that gets created off the bat. I bind it to the fields on the UI and when I an creating the MemberResponse records I set the .AlarmTotal propery with the MemberResponse objects. Everything gets saved on the same call, and still works properly, but I am much more confident in this approach.

Answer (score 4):

First off, your data context is not closed, and you are going to leak a **TON** of memory/bandwidth if you are not closing your database context connections. Please look into that.

Secondly, the method `.SaveChanges()` will figure out what the correct id is to assign depending on the database settings. If there is not a definition there such as `auto-increment` then it is possible that these ids will not be set correctly and you could be saving into the same ID and then throw an exception. The children will have their foreign keys assigned only by explicit association which you are already doing.

**Edit:**

In response to your comment, usually a using statement is used for managing contexts because it is clean code:

```
var members = new Members();
using( var context = new SmokeFireDBEntities())
{
 //use context how you would, i.e.
 members = from m in context.Members
             where new[] { "A", "P", "S", "J" }.Contains(m.Class.ShortName)
             orderby m.Line
             select m;
}//once this is hit the context is closed and you can feel safe about your connection
```

If this approach does not work with how long you want the connection open, you may also manually (although not highly suggested) close the connection on your own.

```
this.dbContext = new SmokeFireDBEntities(); 
var members = from m in dbContext.Members
             where new[] { "A", "P", "S", "J" }.Contains(m.Class.ShortName)
             orderby m.Line
             select m;
this.dbContext.Dispose();//this will close the connection for you, and if you need it re-opened then either call new Entities() again or use the using statement
```

Comment: Good note on the context needing to be closed.

Comment: The fact that he didn't post any code that disposes of the context doesn't mean that he doesn't do so. He might be doint it when closing the form.

Comment: Thanks. You are correct about closing the context. I am not doing that. I am aware of the need for this, but have not looked into this yet as far as how and where the best place is to do this.

Answer (score 2):

Short answer: That's what the Context and the Entiities do; they track all that stuff so that updates to the whole object graph are saved.

By object graph, I mean the "root" object you are working with, and any related items that you might attach, whether you always realize that's what you are doing or not.

It *is* awesome!

EDIT: I recommend reading the excellent work of Julia Lerman if you want to dig more into Entity Framework. It's a very big topic, but it's worth it. She has a canonical book named Entity Framework, and an msdn column, blog, etc.

Note that questions about books are not really on topic here, but I'm suggesting this because you seem new to EF.

Comment: Awesome yes. I love the fact that things happen without much effort, but at the same time it does make them a bit more difficult to understand since you dont see all that background work. I'm still not understanding how the MemberResponse records make it into the database since I have not yet .AddObject()ed it to the context. I am going to read up on it more and step through my code again. Thanks for the reply and the book suggestion